# Ushahidi GET request with multiple parameters

Tags: api, http, get

I'm working on an application that uses Ushahidi to return an array of JSON objects using a HTTP GET request. I would like to use two parameters in the request. These parameters are category id and max id. In the URL below the first parameter is `&by=catid&id=2` and the second is `&by=maxid&id=499`. The example below will only read the last parameter entered. So the catid parameter would be ignored.

```
http://fixyourstreet.ie/api?task=incidents&by=catid&id=2&by=maxid&id=499
```

Why will this request only return JSON objects by the last parameter entered rather than both parameters?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those requests typically get parsed as key-value dictionaries by web servers.
This means the "by" parameter can only have one value when your request is processed and responded to. You will have to make 2 subsequent requests if you need  all these values :

```
 http://fixyourstreet.ie/api?task=incidents&by=catid&id=2
    http://fixyourstreet.ie/api?task=incidents&by=maxid&id=499
```